# How to store a number of a text to a variable (cucumber/capybara)?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm creating a ticket with Cucumber and Capybara, but when it's created I receive an alert with a confirmation message on the HTML page:

*Ticket **6168218** created*

How could I store just the number of this text on a variable?

This is the HTML code:

```
`<div id="messages" class="clearfix">
  <div class="success global alert-default form-section">
    <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Ticket 6168218 created.</li>
    </ul>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="close-alert"><strong>x</strong></a>
   </div>
 </div>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the text of the element with

```
find('.success li').text #change the .success selector if you need more specificity
```

then you can extract the number using a regex.  All together that would be

```
ticket_no = /Ticket (\d+) created/.match(find('.success li').text)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks!
But now I find out that I have to find this number on an id...
Because when I create this ticket, it turn to an id like: 

`<button type="submit" id="assign_ticket_6168218" class="btn btn-primary exchange_button">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Assume
</button>`

When I create the ticket, it is created with a random number, and i have to create and find it.

Can I use a regex on an id? How can I find each ticket that I create?

Comment: @KaueCoelho Then ask a new question with the correct html

Comment: Ok, i'll do this! Thank you